# Google Fonts not working in Internet explorer

Tags: html, css, fonts, google-font-api

I've been developing a site that uses the Google Fonts API. It's great, and supposedly has been tested in IE, but when testing in IE 8 the fonts simply don't get styled. The Special character is showing in bold fonts in internet explorer.

```
<link  href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,300i,400,400i,600,700" rel="stylesheet" href="" />

 <span class="base" data-ui-id="page-title-wrapper">Glyndŵr's Way</span>

span{ font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;    font-weight: 300;
font-size: 40px;}
```

Comment: why is there 2 href?

Comment: The answer to this one is "Who cares.". Also you should edit the title to include the 8.